# Scons Multi-Directory copying/zipping

Tags: python, scons

**Problem:**

I have 2 source directories, one in the "current" dir and one in some other directory"

1: C:/somedir/dir_a/[win32, win64]/[tests, documentation, a, b]

And
2: D:/projects/project_a/api/[win32, win64]/[tests, a, b, c]

sconstruct @ D:/projects/project_a/sconstruct

Now I would like to have both directories in a zip file, with the root "win32".
Directory 2 (D:/..) has it's win32 folder + content copied in the sconstruct already which means (afaik) that D:/projects/project_a/api/win32 (or win64) is already a target as far as scons is concerned.

**What I tried:**

When I then try to copy over directory 1 (c:/..) to directory 2, it simply won't because the target is already there. So that's the first attempt already.

Second attempt I used env.Zip to get the 2 directories in a Zip, this worked, however they are rooted completely wrong. The zip looked as follows:

```
zip..somedir/dir_a/win32/[tests, documentation, a, b]
   |.api/win32/[tests, a, b, c]
```

Where I would have wanted:

```
zip..win32/[tests, documentation, a, b, c]
```

Is there any way of doing this in Scons properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found Solution:**

Hi All,

found a proper solution for the root-less copytree problem I had.

Using the Accumulator found @ http://www.scons.org/wiki/AccumulateBuilder

Then just calling it as:

```
target = "dir where you want to copy contents of source"
basedir = "source dir containing content to be copied"
env.Accumulate(target, [os.path.join(basedir ,x) for x in os.listdir(basedir)])
```

Hope this helps someone else in the future with a similar problem :)